# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile Compilation failure: Compilation failure:

Tags: maven, plugins, compilation

I am trying to create a sample maven project but it is throwing the below error. I added all the required jars on the project. Not sure what is the issue.

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project MySampleProj: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
```

Any help would be appreciated.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>MySampleProj</groupId>
    <artifactId>MySampleProj</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>MySampleProj</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>

        <maven-compiler-plugin-version>3.7.0</maven-compiler-plugin-version>

        <cxf.version>3.1.6</cxf.version>
        <jra.version>2.1.16</jra.version>
        <jdk.version>1.7</jdk.version>
        <jaxws.version>2.0.1</jaxws.version>
        <spring.version>5.0.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.6.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.11</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
                <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
                <version>4.5.5</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
                <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
                <version>4.5.5</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven 
                defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${maven-compiler-plugin-version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                        <fork>true</fork>
                        <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                        <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                        <compilerVersion>${java.version}</compilerVersion>
                        <executable>${java.home}/bin/javac</executable>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <!-- <plugin> <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> 
                    <version>3.7.0</version> <configuration> <release>8</release> <verbose>true</verbose> 
                    </configuration> </plugin> -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.7.0</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.20.1</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>



Class

import java.net.URLEncoder;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.Header;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod;

public class DemoRestClient {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

                DemoRestClient restClient = new DemoRestClient(); 
                try { 
                    restClient.getBook("Naked Sun"); 
                } catch (Exception e) { 
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            } 
            public BookVO getBook(String bookName) throws Exception { 
                String output = null; 
                try{ 
                    String url = "http://localhost:8080/weblog4jdemo/bookservice/getbook/"; 
                    url = url + URLEncoder.encode(bookName, "UTF-8"); 
                    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(); 
                    PostMethod mPost = new PostMethod(url); 
                    client.executeMethod( mPost ); 
                    Header mtHeader = new Header(); 
                    mtHeader.setName("content-type"); 
                    mtHeader.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
                    mtHeader.setName("accept"); 
                    mtHeader.setValue("application/xml"); 
                    mPost.addRequestHeader(mtHeader); 
                    client.executeMethod(mPost); 
                    output = mPost.getResponseBodyAsString( ); 
                    mPost.releaseConnection( ); 
                    System.out.println("out : " + output); 
                }catch(Exception e){ 
                    throw new Exception("Exception in retriving group page info : " + e); 
                } 
                return null; 
            } 
            public void addBook(String bookName, String author) throws Exception { 
                String output = null; 
                try{ 
                    String url = "http://localhost:8080/weblog4jdemo/bookservice/addbook"; 
                    HttpClient client = new HttpClient(); 
                    PostMethod mPost = new PostMethod(url); 
                    mPost.addParameter("name", "Naked Sun"); 
                    mPost.addParameter("author", "Issac Asimov"); 
                    Header mtHeader = new Header(); 
                    mtHeader.setName("content-type"); 
                    mtHeader.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); 
                    mtHeader.setName("accept"); 
                    mtHeader.setValue("application/xml"); 
                    mPost.addRequestHeader(mtHeader); 
                    client.executeMethod(mPost); 
                    output = mPost.getResponseBodyAsString( ); 
                    mPost.releaseConnection( ); 
                    System.out.println("output : " + output); 
                }catch(Exception e){ 
                throw new Exception("Exception in adding bucket : " + e); 
                } 
            } 
    }


Console output






[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project MySampleProj: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/User....DemoRestClient.java:[5,37] package org.apache.commons.httpclient does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/User....DemoRestClient.java:[7,37] package org.apache.commons.httpclient does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/User....DemoRestClient.java::[8,45] package org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/User....DemoRestClient.java:[7,24] package javax.ws.rs.core does not exist
[ERROR] /C:/User....DemoRestClient.java:[12,1] package javax.ws.rs does not exist
```

Comment: I have just looked at one of my `pom.xml` files and I don't seem to use the `<dependencyManagement>` tag... I just have all dependencies directly below `<project>`... not sure if that's the issue but worth a try. And this also applies to the `<pluginManagement>` tag.

Comment: hi Ovimunt, I did eleminated the tags but stilli see this BUILD FAILURE
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.7.0:compile (default-compile) on project MySampleProj: Compilation failure -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]